# WooCommerce reference hooked template for sku wrapper

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, product

I couldn't find the right SKU wrapper reference hooked template in WooCommerce documentation.

What I want to do is to change the sky wrapper / span from the product summary to the after product summary, like this:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_SKUwrapper???', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_SKUwrapper???', 60 );
```

Any thoughts on this? >br>
Am I doing this correctly and just need the sku wrapper reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> There is **no** wrapper SKU hook (or dedicated template) in WooCommerce single product pages…

The code that output SKU is located in **`single-product/meta.php.php`** template:

```
<?php if ( wc_product_sku_enabled() && ( $product->get_sku() || $product->is_type( 'variable' ) ) ) : ?>

    <span class="sku_wrapper"><?php esc_html_e( 'SKU:', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="sku"><?php echo ( $sku = $product->get_sku() ) ? $sku : esc_html__( 'N/A', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span></span>

<?php endif; ?>
```

To change the location "after product summary" you will have to remove this code and place it in content-single-product.php after **`do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );`**

Official Documentation: [**Template Structure + Overriding Templates via a Theme**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)